# Spring annotations configuration looks like overhead

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, overhead

I just faced,that in order to use specific annotations for Spring Security,
 I should explicitely allow them in my config(applicationContext.xml)
Example:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
<sec:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
...
```

What advantages do you see in approach of ***explicitely declare what annotations***
 are allowed in our frameworked application?

Looks like overconfiguration,isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible benefit is that it allows Spring Security to throw an exception when desired annotations are not present in the classpath (though it's mostly about JSR-250 annotations, since other annotations are parts of Spring Security itself).

Otherwise Spring Security would have to silently ignore absence of annotations, that may lead to surprising behaviour.

Comment: possible it may serves as advise to other developers what annotations are allowed in system